# What is the best option to process a queue of orders (Redis)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis

I have a front-end page where the customer can send an order of purchase then this order is pushed into a queue in Redis. After that I have some workers poping this information from the queue and process this front-end information to persist in several Mongo collections.

I already read some articles about Redis and I'm trying understand the best solution for this question, but i really appreciate some opinions about this topic and maybe other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on requirement you have. There are few options like

1. Kue:- Kue is a priority job queue backed by redis, built for node.js.
2. Bull:- The fastest, most reliable, Redis-based queue for Node.

I have used both of them, rather I have used Kue for production purpose.

Also, as you are using Mongodb, you can opt for "**Agenda**" npm package. I have used this package in one of my project.

You can compare all these three and chose the best one which suits the best for requirement.